# Conexão ao banco de dados com App.config

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, app.config

Como estabelecer uma conexão ao banco de dados Northwind usando `App.config` e ADO.NET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acho que é isto que você deseja:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Northwind;IntegratedSecurity=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>  
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Código:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public class Programa {
    public static void Main() {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Configuration.cs).